# Why are the last few pages of the activity tab blank under a tag's Documentation dashboard?

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, user-interface

In many tags, the last few pages of the activity tab under the tag's Documentation dashboard are blank. [For example Android](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android?tab=activity&subtab=none&page=138):

> [image]

Why is this so?

Comment: Possibly because of spam submissions that were deleted from the database, but only partially?

Comment: i.e. caching :D

Comment: Last page with content as of 2016-12-30 19:31:31Z: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android?tab=activity&subtab=none&page=129

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The count query didn't match the actual retrieval query. They'll be in sync starting with the next build. Thanks for the report!